# how to print the row numbers in a 2d array game board in java

Tags: java

I am working on a java Othello game and am using a 2D array with padding to build the board. I have the board printing just fine, the columns are labeled "a -h" but i need the rows to be numberd "1-8" and cannot figure out how to do this. my code is as follows:

```
 void printBoard() {
        String results = "";
        OthelloOut.printComment("   a b c d e f g h");
        int row = board.board.length;
        int col = board.board[0].length;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                results += " " + pieces[board.board[i][j] + 2];
            }
            OthelloOut.printComment(results);
            results = "";
        }
    }
```

the othelloOut class sort of extends the System.out print statements

```
public class OthelloOut {
    static public void printMove(PieceColor color, Move amove){
        System.out.printf("%s %s\n", color, amove);        
    }//printMove
    static public void printComment(String str){
        System.out.printf("C %s\n", str);        
    }//printComment
    static public void printReady(PieceColor color){
        System.out.printf("R %s\n", color);
    }//printReady    
}//OthelloOut
```

any help will be much appreciated. If this needs to be clarified more just let me know! thanks.

UPDATE: Numbers print but i prints 0 - 9 and i want it to skip the digits 0 and 9 to where its blank in the positions of those two numbers. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is doing it here:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        OthelloOut.printComment(i); // Obviously not exactly like this.
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            results += " " + pieces[board.board[i][j] + 2];
        }
        OthelloOut.printComment(results);
        results = "";
    }
```

Remember that you're not using `println`, you're using `print`. You want all other text to be printed onto the same line as i.

**And while I'm here..**

I would be using a `StringBuilder`, instead of concatenating a `String`.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();
        OthelloOut.printComment(i); // Obviously not exactly like this.
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            results.append(pieces[board.board[i][j] + 2]);
        }
        OthelloOut.printComment(results.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the row number at each **row iteration** like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    results += i + 1;  // add the row number
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        results += " " + pieces[board.board[i][j] + 2];
    }
    OthelloOut.printComment(results);
    results = "";
}
```